# Waiting for "gazebo_msgs/GetLinkState" causes Python to freeze

Tags: ros, gazebo7, python2.7, rospy, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 with Gazebo 7.3.0 and Python 2.7:

I have an issue withs starting a Gazebo service proxy for getting link states programmatically from a Python file I run after running the launch file that starts the Gazebo world.
At the top of the file I have:

```
from gazebo_msgs.srv import GetLinkState 
from gazebo_msgs.msg import LinkState # For getting information about link states
```

...

Later in the file I have:

```
# Get model information from Gazebo
# Get a handle to the Gazebo model spawner
model_info_prox = rospy.ServiceProxy('gazebo_msgs/GetLinkState', GetLinkState) # No error here
rospy.wait_for_service('gazebo_msgs/GetLinkState') # <-- Python hangs here without error
print model_info_prox( "lbr4_allegro" , "lbr4_7_link" ) # Never makes it here
```

The script freezes waiting for link states to become available, as noted above.  Why does this happen?  I used a similar pattern for spawning models and it works fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240371/waiting-for-%22gazebo_msgs/getlinkstate%22-causes-python-to-freeze/) by [jwatson_utah_edu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27605/jwatson_utah_edu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-07-26**:
Have you confirmed that the service exists? (Is it listed in 'rosservice list'?)

**Comment by [jwatson_utah_edu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27605/jwatson_utah_edu/) on 2016-07-26**:
No, I had not.  I grabbed the service name from a post elsewhere online.  I was able to find the correct servive with `rosservice list`.  See below. Thanks, @NEngelhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- The problem is that the name of the service is incorrect.  In Gazebo 7.3, the `/gazebo/get_link_state` service is offered, according to `rosservice list`.  As written above, the node will be waiting for a service that will never start.
- The link name should be scoped with the model in a single name, not split into two names.
- Also, the link state service requires a reference frame with respect to which the link pose will be reported.

The last three lines should be:

```
model_info_prox = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/get_link_state', GetLinkState)
rospy.wait_for_service('/gazebo/get_link_state')
print "Link 7 Pose:"    , endl , model_info_prox( "lbr4_allegro::lbr4_7_link" , "world" )
```

---

Originally posted by [jwatson_utah_edu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27605/jwatson_utah_edu/) with karma: 56 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1